# Ambiguous tag: Jet

Tags: discussion, tags

Jet is defined as (excerpt) :

```
Jet is the SQL database engine used by Microsoft Windows.
It is also used by Microsoft Access; Jet databases are more commonly 
known as "Access databases".
```

Unfortunately, Jet is also `Java Emitter Templates`

Which leads to [some problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jet), more specifically https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11841785/how-to-use-jet-for-generation-class-with-methods.

There is a tag [ms-jet-ace](/questions/tagged/ms-jet-ace), which might be more suitable for the Jet database, especially if it was changed to the more intuitive [jet-ace](/questions/tagged/jet-ace), which would leave [jet](/questions/tagged/jet) to Java. Alternatively, the Java tags could be moved to, say, [jet-java](/questions/tagged/jet-java), which might be more appropriate, as this usage seems to be the newer one. Finally, all jet entries could be retagged and the ambiguous tag removed.

What does the panel think?

Comment: Agree with you, "jet" is too generic. If you get consensus then let me know if you need help retagging.

Comment: @JimmyPena, I will thanks. I am waiting a bit at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll agree that it's ambiguous, although I think the Microsoft usage would take precedence, if either of them would. I think I'd want [eclipse-jet](/questions/tagged/eclipse-jet), or [jet-eclipse](/questions/tagged/jet-eclipse) .

Comment: [tag:eclipse-jet] sounds like the right one.

Comment: I prefer jet-eclipse, because when someone starts to type `jet`, it will pop up nicely.

Comment: @Remou: It works anywhere in the tag name.

Comment: Oops, good point :) del, del ..

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest keeping [jet](/questions/tagged/jet) as-is and using [java-emitter-templates](/questions/tagged/java-emitter-templates) for the Java one. The majority of the current [jet](/questions/tagged/jet) questions seem to follow the tag wiki correctly, and it's a more logical name.

Comment: The reason I did not suggest the full name, even though it would be a very nice solution, is that people will continue to type Jet, and  `java-emitter-templates` does not even begin with `je`, so the problem will remain of Java questions tagged `jet`.

Comment: @Remou: Just include "JET" as an abbreviation in the tag wiki, and it'll still show up.

Comment: @minitech I did not know that, it must be new. Very useful.

Comment: Hi minitech, it is now 17 hours and there is still a tie on this. I think you voted for Ernest's proposal, is that correct? The alternative is to use both options and see which one wins with users.

Comment: @Remou: Well, we both voted for each other's.

Comment: Deary me. I guess I will have to bump in some way and hope for more people with an opinion.

Comment: I have retagged with both `java-emitter-templates` and `eclipse-jet`. One of them should win. I have added a note to the [Jet wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jet/info).

Comment: @Remou: Don't do that, duplicate tags are a Bad Thing. Maybe you ought to wait more than one day before making a decision?

Comment: Too late, but there are only 4/5 retags, so it is not a massive problem. I will check again and fix it in a day or two.

Comment: eclipse-jet won.