# Ambiguous tag: Android JET / Microsoft Jet

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, ambiguous-tags

Another use for the JET tag has just come to my attention, as noted below. I am tempted to use either [android-jet] or [jet-audio] for the latest manifestation.

Edit: I have assigned [jet-audio](/questions/tagged/jet-audio) as a holder, there is only one tagged item so far.

Does the panel agree?

**Relevant Information**

Related meta question: [Ambiguous tag: Jet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142546/ambiguous-tag-jet/142551#142551)

[Existing Jet wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jet/info)

[Further information on Android JET](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/android/devguide/guide/topics/media/index.html)

> The Android platform includes a JET engine that lets you add
>   interactive playback of JET audio content in your applications. You
>   can create JET content for interactive playback using the JetCreator
>   authoring application that ships with the SDK. To play and manage JET
>   content from your application, use the JetPlayer class.

Sample Stack Overflow question: [Is the Android JET file format proprietory, or is it open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375496/is-the-android-jet-file-format-proprietory-or-is-it-open)

Comment: @Bart I am curious about your edit. The tags do not yet exist, so why format as tags? It seems ambiguous to me, suggesting that they are already available.

Comment: Bah, I frankly misread the question, in the process assuming those tags existed. And they were formatted as code to begin with, which you shouldn't do. If you feel it confuses things, write something like [android-jet] instead. I think no harm is really done here.

Comment: If the format I used is code format I would *love* to know why it is used for every-second-word in SO. :)

Comment: Because people confuse it for a general highlighting tool, which it isn't, making idiots like me go around and edit such nonsense out of their posts. ;)

Comment: related: [A real solution to ambiguous tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125234/165773)